# let X has a finite dimensional show that X is reflexive.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, reflection

We know If a normed space X is reflexive, then $X'$ is reflexive.and also Reflexive normed spaces are Banach.

but can you proof if X has a finite dimensional Then X is reflexive.

Comment: Has a finite dimensional "what"?

Comment: dim X < infinity....

Comment: Do you know $\mathrm{dim}(X) = \mathrm{dim}(X^*)$?

Comment: yes...i know...

Answer (score 2):

We have $\mathrm{dim}(X) = \mathrm{dim}(X^*) = \mathrm{dim}(X^{**})$. Since the canonical embedding $J : X \to X^{**}$ is an isometry, it is surjective (consider the dimensions). Hence, by definition, $X$ is reflexive.